# word 2007 vba can't delete all the autoshape line at once

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-2007

i'm using the following code to select and delete all autoshape lines in the document.

It works fine in MSWord 2003. (Also for the lines drawn using 2003 when opened in 2007)
But its not selecting the lines which are drawn in MS word 2007.

```
Sub line() 
Dim shp As Shape, intBoxNbr As Integer

intNbrShapes = 0
For Each shp In ActiveDocument.Shapes
If shp.Type = msoLine Then
intNbrShapes = intNbrShapes + 1
ActiveWindow.ScrollIntoView Selection.Range, True
shp.Select
Selection.Delete
'shp.Delete
'(Selection.Delete is used in MSWord 2007 and shp.Delete used in MSWord 2003)
End If
Next shp

End Sub
```

I found that the line drawn in MSword 2007 has the name as Autoshape##, where 2003 has line##.
I have other auto shapes (text box etc) in the document so i cant use just "If shp.Type = msoAutoShape Then".
please help how to select and just delete line drawn using MS word 2007.

thanks.

I updated the code now... its not removing all the lines at once. i need to run the macro multiple times to remove all.

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
Dim shp As Shape, i As Integer

i = 0
For Each shp In ActiveDocument.Shapes
If shp.Type = msoAutoShape Then
i = i + 1
ActiveWindow.ScrollIntoView Selection.Range, True
shp.Select

If Selection.ShapeRange.Line.DashStyle = msoLineSolid Then
Selection.Delete
End If

'shp.Delete

End If
Next shp

End Sub
```

Comment: What have you done to debug? Put a breakpoint on your `For Each shp` statement, and check the `shp.Type` property for a known "line". It may not be of type `msoLine`, and that would obviously then "fail" to select/delete such shapes.

Comment: can you brief me a little more.

Comment: I don't have either 2003 or 2007 available to test these conditions, and in 2010, the shapes default names are not like what you describe (instead, I get "Straight Connector 1", etc.).  So, you should do some debugging and try to tinker with the various properties to see what is possible.

Comment: Why don't people understand that code is absolutely illegible when you put it in the *comments*?

Comment: When deleting items from a collection, it is always necessary to iterate backwards through the collection.

Comment: Revise your Q to include that code. Also, please clarify what precisely is the problem and you have arrived at that. For example, previously you indicate some difficulty determining the version origin of each shape. Are you sure that's actually relevant? Or if, after debugging you realize that maybe some shapes are not deleted because you're indexing incorrectly, then state that as the problem.

Comment: I have updated the question also my problem is that the code i have not deleting the autoshape line (straight connector) all at once.

Comment: David Zemens could you please try and let me know?

Answer (score 1):

When you are removing items from a collection, it is necessary to do this in *reverse* order. This is because collections are indexed. Consider the following example collection:

```
Item#  Name
  1      David
  2      Sergio
  3      Beatrice
  4      Eunice
```

If we do attempt to delete all items by straight iteration from 1 to .Count, it will not work:

```
Sub foo()
Dim coll As New Collection
Dim i As Integer

coll.Add 1, "David"
coll.Add 2, "Sergio"
coll.Add 3, "Beatrice"
coll.Add 4, "Eunice"

For i = 1 To coll.Count
    coll.Remove (i)
Next

MsgBox coll.Count

End Sub
```

On the first iteration, i = 1 and it will remove "David", on the second pass, i = 2, but since item 1 was previously removed, the second index is now "Beatrice", so "Sergio" is skipped. And on the third iteration, i = 3 but there is no longer 3 items in the collection and you will get an error! (subscript out of range). If you have not encountered the error yet, that is possible.

So, to avoid this problem, you need to step backwards:

```
For i = coll.Count to 1 Step -1
    coll.Remove(i)
Next
```

This means you have to use an indexed iteration rather than a `For Each`, so adapted to your code, you can try like:

```
For i = ActiveDocument.Shapes.Count to 1 Step - 1
    Set shp = ActiveDocument.Shapes(i)

    If shp.Type = msoAutoShape Then

        ActiveWindow.ScrollIntoView Selection.Range, True
        shp.Select

        If Selection.ShapeRange.Line.DashStyle = msoLineSolid Then
            Selection.Delete
        End If
    End If
Next
```